# google dns query response translate

Tags: dns, iis-8, windows-server-2012

hi guys i have problem with this DNS itbime.com, when i put this dns inside of [google Public DNS](https://dns.google.com/query?name=itbime.com&type=A&dnssec=true)

its will give me this response

```
{
  "Status": 3,
  "TC": false,
  "RD": true,
  "RA": true,
  "AD": false,
  "CD": false,
  "Question": [
    {
      "name": "itbime.com.",
      "type": 1
    }
  ],
  "Authority": [
    {
      "name": "com.",
      "type": 6,
      "TTL": 899,
      "data": "a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1600782058 1800 900 604800 86400"
    }
  ],
  "Comment": "Response from 192.31.80.30."
```

i just want to know what is meaning of status:3 and what is wrong with my domain (itbime.com)

Comment: guys i really need help here, plz put some time for me

Comment: 3 means 'NXDOMAIN' (https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml#dns-parameters-6). That code is coming from .com, who are saying your domain does not exist. A DNS query (`dig  itbime.com @c.gtld-servers.net`) directly to the .com servers indeed reports NXDOMAIN. You need to talk to your registrar. A whois query reports your domain is in `clientHold`. You need to talk to your registrar.

Comment: tanx dude that is right , i am from iran and tanx to us embargo our domain removed